# What is 'CTLoader', a bundle I found on my OSX drive, which program does it come from?

Tags: macos, mac

I have a file ~/CTLoader/ct_loader.bundle on my drive, and I wonder where it comes from, what it is for... Did you ever see that? The resource files in the bundle do not provide any clue...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a component of a "Vuze Toolbar for Safari", apparently.

Comment: Indeed. Found a few things on Google about that. Thanks

Comment: Ugh! So Vuze is silently bundling adware toolbars even on Mac now? This software just gets worse and worse every month.